# Create routes with controllers in Slim 3 like in Laravel 5

Tags: php, slim, slim-3

With the PHP framework Slim 3 in Routes, I did this:

```
// In routes :
$app->get('article/{id}-{slug}', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    $class = new Site\ArticleController($args);
    $class->show();
});

// In controllers :
public function show($args)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = $args['id'] AND slug = $args['slug']";
    // ...
}
```

In Laravel 5 this coudl be written like:

```
// In routes :
Route::get('article/{id}-{slug}', 'Site\ArticleController@show');

// In controllers :
public function show($id, $slug)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = $id AND slug = $slug";
    // ...
}
```

Can we do the same with Slim 3? I mean this:

```
$app::get('article/{id}-{slug}', 'Site\ArticleController@show');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can structure Slim 3 routes similar to Laravel by doing something like this:

```
<?php
// In routes :
$app->get('article/{id}-{slug}', '\Site\ArticleController:show');

// In controllers :
public function show($request, $response, $args)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = $args['id'] AND slug = $args['slug']";
    // ...
}
```

The Slim router now passes $request and $response in the first and second parameters and then any Route arguments you set in the last $args.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: @Davide OK. Thank you

Comment: @stephweb The answer is from Dbeazy. :)